# Shape preserving transformations that don't "qualify" as symmetries

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry

Consider a square. We can rotate it by multiples of 90 degs or reflect it in 4 ways, and we get $D_4$. This is the typical basic approach to constructing symmetry groups.

However, these are not all the transformations that preserve the square. For example, we can take two points on the square and replace them, or in general "shuffle around" points in an arbitrary way. These are not considered part of what defines the symmetry group of the square, because they do not preserve distances (e.g. the two points that were replaced are no longer of the same distance to some third point).

Nevertheless, if we include all such transformations, they seem to also form groups (is this true?). Is there any name and/or use to such "enlarged symmetries"?

Considering *all* possible ways to reshuffle points seems uninteresting, because every geometric object is trivially invariant to relabeling of its points. Thus preservation of distances gives a meaningful constraint that limits possible permutations to more "rigid" transformations. But how about slightly less stringent constraints, or replacing distance preservation with some other desirable property?

Are there examples of such constructions?

Comment: There are many such things you can do depending on what you want to preserve. For example if you only ask to preserve the topology you get a much larger group, the homeomorphism group of the square.

Comment: This group is just the full symmetry group of the set of points in the square, But this group doesn’t particularly have anything to do with a square, just the cardinality of the set of points, so we don’t think of it as a group of symmetries of the square.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the "full transformation" of $n+1$ points as points of same distance to each other in $\mathbb R^n$. Then the transformation always preserves distance.

For example we have equilateral triangle in $\mathbb R^2$, regular tetrahedron in $\mathbb R^3$, and so on.

The of the "full transformation" of $n$ points is usually called the [Symmetric Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) of order $n$, denoted as $S_n$. And usually $D_{n}$ is called the [Dihedral Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group), which means $n$ points in  a plane under reflection and rotation. It is sometimes also written as $D_{2n}$ to denote the group having $2n$ elements.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I'm wrong but: 1. if you take e.g. the tip of an equilateral triangle and replace it with the midpoint of an edge, it will not preserve the distance of these points to a second tip (since the tip-tip distance is different from mid-tip). Does distance preservation mean something else, e.g. excluding overall rescaling? But then this is trivial because you don't map a shape to itself but to some other shape.
2. Is there much sense to $S_{\aleph_0}$? I know $S_\infty$ is meaningful, but that is really $S_{\mathbb N}$ as far as I understand.